# How do I parse a log from a game with regex and/or linq?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I'm looking for the most elegant way to parse this. I'm just hitting a wall when it comes to my regex knowledge and maybe a regex is not even the best answer?

I have three example sentences to give an example of what I want to do. I want to to parse these into four parts. Attacker, attack-type, damage and target.

> Gandalfs's heavenly wrath DISMEMBERS you!
>
> The Holy Prelate's slash wounds Frodo.
>
> Your divine power decimates the evil Warlock!

Attacker:
One or several words that are always first and the words can be identified by either being "Your" or end in 's.

Attack-type: One or several words that can only be identified by that they are between the "attacker" and the "damage".

Damage: One or more (rare but exists) words that are unique and limited. I have a list with possible words. {"wounds", "decimates" etc}. They do not exists anywhere else so no risk that the attacker is named "wounds" or something like that.

Target: One or several words that can be identified that they are all the words after the damage.

Comment: In your example `Your divine power decimates the evil Warlock!`, is the target `the evil Warlock`, `evil Warlock`, or just `Warlock`?

Comment: It should be `the evil Warlock` according to the description, no?

Comment: "the evil Warlock" is correct yes

Comment: Are these MUD logs? I love MUDs :)

Comment: They are MUD logs yes, not "real" names though. They are from www.carrionfields.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will return a match with four captures for each line:

```
^((?<attacker>Your)|(?<attacker>.*?)'s)\s+(?<type>.*\S?)\s+(?<damage>wounds|decimates|dismembers)\s+(?<target>.*)\p{P}\s*?$
```

Note that you need to use the following regex options for it to work:

- IgnoreCase
- MultiLine
- ExplicitCapture

You can then query the value of the groups (attacker, type, damage, target) for each match.

Note that you need to complete the list of damages.

My regex test application set to process all matches returns the following for your test data and my regex:

```
Attacker: Gandalfs
Type: heavenly wrath
Damage: DISMEMBERS
Target: you

Attacker: The Holy Prelate
Type: slash
Damage: wounds
Target: Frodo

Attacker: Your
Type: divine power
Damage: decimates
Target: the evil Warlock
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to register on this site so I can vote you up too.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best off with a proper lexer/parser.

I'd investigate ANTLR:

http://www.antlr.org/

It has a great UI, you can design your language, test it and the have ANTLR generate C# that will build the syntax tree.

This kind of parsing isn't really suited to regex, and doesn't have anything to do with LINQ.

Comment: Why not a regex? The terminals in the grammar would have to be pretty much the same as the regex and the grammar would just have one production with the four parts, so that's pretty pointless IMHO.